# How to get datakeyvalue of listview in row checked

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I want when I click button checkbox i get data key value in row have checkbox is checked. Anyone have idea

```
<asp:ListView ID="rlv_CouponCode" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="sds_CouponCode" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlace">
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="Checkbox1" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox Enabled="false" ID="Checkbox" runat="server"
                Text='<%#Eval("Code") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox Enabled="false" ID="NameLabel" runat="server"
                Text='<%#Eval("Discount") %>' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Here my code behind for Button1:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem item in rlv_CouponCode.Items)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("Checkbox1");
        if (cb.Checked)
        {
           //
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have have set `DataKeyNames`, so you can access those.

```
for (int i = 0; i < rlv_CouponCode.Items.Count; i++)
{
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)rlv_CouponCode.Items[i].FindControl("Checkbox1");

    if (cb.Checked)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(rlv_CouponCode.DataKeys[i].Values[0]);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your checkbox an ID that is the Id of the records it is displaying. This way each checkbox will have a unique ID that you can use to process the data. For example if your data has `CouponID` then:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID='<%#Eval("CouponID") %>' runat="server" />
```

On the server side get it using that ID and see if it has been checked.

Comment: But if set ID checkbox = CouponID, how can i get what checkbox is checked, because i use `(CheckBox)item.FindControl("Checkbox1")`